# Linux Redirect www to non-www using .htaccess

Tags: linux, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect `www.example.com` to `http://example.com` using the `.htaccess` file in my root directory.

I've tried the examples listed here and elsewhere. `rewriteengine` is on.

```
rewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
rewriteRule (.*) //%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I've plugged this in in different spots of my `.htaccess` file, and I get redirect errors, saying it's improperly redirected.

In the above example, do I need to plug my actual site information in somewhere?  If so, can someone give me an example using `www.example.com`?

I'm on a Linux based server, through GoDaddy.

Comment: You can't use a protocol-relative URL in the `RewriteRule` substitution. It's simply seen as relative to the document root (as is any URL that starts with a slash).

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.org$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.org/$1
```

Comment: Joni, thanks.  I entered in your code after inputting my domain info and I got a 500 Internal Server Error, however I noticed it was an Apache server.  

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you see error logs? I don't know how to see them trough Godaddy.

Comment: Got anything that also shows http/https depending on how they came in?

Answer (score 0):

You presently have

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.) [NC]
RewriteRule (.) //%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I think you're almost there. Remember that in a regular expression a single dot `.` matches a *single* character. If you want to match one-or-more characters then try `.+`. And if you want to match zero-or-more characters then use `.*`. E.g.:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

(you also need the leading `http:` for the redirect URL).

Comment: "`(.)`" - You only saw the single dots in the original question because it was incorrectly formatted. The pattern was really `(.*)` - the asterisk was simply hidden because it wasn't formatted as a _code block_ (the markdown parser stripped it).